# Sentient cities on post-apocalyptic Earth

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I am trying to identify a short story I read long ago. The plot involved sentient cities which moved bodily around a deserted Earth. The humans living in them had over the centuries been expelled, because the cities had been programmed to respond to any criminal infraction, no matter how minor, with exile. The story must have been from the 1940s-1980s.

Answer (score 8):

This is most likely Greg Bear's [*Strength of Stones*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0743452631). I can't find a Wikipedia link, but it was published in 1981.

Comment: I think you're right. Thank you so much!

Comment: @user15385 Please accept the answer if it's correct.

Comment: Haha,I was about to comment that the synopsis